# Check Ruby HTTP response for success

Tags: ruby, net-http

How does one properly check the response from Net::HTTP::Get (for example) for "success" (i.e., a 2xx return code)?  The documentation seems to be sadly silent on this simple question.

I have:

```
response=Net::HTTP.new( host, port ).request my_get_request # details not important
```

After a bunch of Googling and near-random typing, I finally determined that this works:

```
response.class < Net::HTTPSuccess
```

Is that actually the canonical way to do it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

For `Net::HTTP`, yes, checking the class of the response object is the way to do it. Using [`kind_of?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F) (aliased also as [`is_a?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F)) is a bit clearer (but functionally equivalent to using [`<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3C)):

```
response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
```

Calling [`value`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-value) on `response` will also raise a `Net::HTTPError` if the status code was not a successful one (what a poorly named method…).

If you can, you may want to consider using a gem instead of `Net::HTTP`, as they often offer better APIs and performance. [Typhoeus](http://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus) and [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) are two good ones, [among others](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).

Comment: Thanks!  Couldn't find a single example anywhere.

Comment: Is this for any response 2xx, or also 3xx? Can't find any docs on it.

Comment: @Maarten 3xx is not a successful response as defined in HTTP, and Net::HTTP abides by that. 3xx would be of type `Net::HTTPRedirection`.

Comment: Then I guess anyone using this should be aware that servers may return `304 Not Modified`, and so may want to check for `Net::HTTPRedirection` cases as well!

Comment: This code reads funny. "response kinda success? Nah, not really. This part was good, though". :)

Comment: This code has a hidden bomb inside. When response code is `204` `response.body` is `nil`. So if you want to check like `is_a? Net::HTTPSuccess` you have to use `response.body || ''`

Comment: Man, I thought you were kidding about `value` being misnamed, like maybe it read the `body` and would _also_ `raise` when the response is not successful. Nope! Literally, it's only purpose is to `Raise an HTTP error if the response is not 2xx (success).` Unreal. Very poor choice of word. Would have expected `success?` or `successful?` or `okay?`.

Answer (score 23):

You can take advantage of Ruby's `case` statement which idiomatically performs class comparisons, thanks to its use of [===](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) under the hood.

Here's an example from a JSON client that catches particular errors but otherwise just returns the server's message:

```
  case response
    when Net::HTTPSuccess
      JSON.parse response.body
    when Net::HTTPUnauthorized
      {'error' => "#{response.message}: username and password set and correct?"}
    when Net::HTTPServerError
      {'error' => "#{response.message}: try again later?"}
    else
      {'error' => response.message}
  end
```

Note above [Net::HTTPResponse parent classes](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPResponse) (e.g. `Net::HTTPServerError`) work too.

Answer (score 4):

If all you're looking to grab is the HTTP status code of an external API or website, then try [`Net::HTTP.get_response`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response).

`Net::HTTP.get(url)` returns a string. You won't be able to easily parse the header response from it:

```
url = URI('http://example.com')
string_response = Net::HTTP.get(url)
# => "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        body {\n            background-color: #fff;\n        }\n        div {\n            width: auto;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            border-radius: 0;\n            padding: 1em;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"

string_response.class
# => String
string_response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
# => false

status_response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
# => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
status_response.class
# => Net::HTTPOK
status_response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
# => true
```