# Check if webpage is online, with Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl

With `curl`, I do the following to check if a webpage is online:

```
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "${url}"; then
  echo "URL exists: ${url}"
else
  echo "URL does not exist: ${url}"
fi
```

However, if the server refuses `HEAD` requests (or I don’t know), an alternative is to request only the first byte of the file:

```
if curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail --range 0-0 "${url}"; then
  echo "URL exists: ${url}"
else
  echo "URL does not exist: ${url}"
fi
```

The first case is easy to replicate in Ruby:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

if response.kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
  puts "URL exists: #{url}"
else
  puts "URL does not exist: #{url}"
end
```

How do I replicate the second `curl` case?

Comment: You can use something like 'curb' (requires libcurl) but nutshell is https://stackoverflow.com/q/82349/438992

Comment: `kind_of?` compares the class of the object, not the object itself. Consider: `case (response)` and then `when Net::HTTPOK` which covers off more cases.

Comment: @tadman Can you expand on that? I took the `response.kind_of?` code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023273/1661012

Comment: It's an uglier way of doing what's in the answer below that by tantrix.

Comment: @tadman “Ugly” is relative. `kind_of?` allows checking in one line: `puts "URL exists: #{url}" if response.kind_of? Net::HTTPOK`.

Comment: How exactly do you define that a _website is online_? Must it respond with a 200 or a 2xx status code? What about a blank `204 No Content`? Or must it include a body? What about a website that responds with a redirect? I would argue that _online_ must be defined first.

Comment: That's also uglier in a way that [Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will flag. Honestly `Net::HTTP` is pretty trash and you should avoid it unless you're aiming for absolutely minimal dependencies, such as inside a published gem. In every other case tools like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) work much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range option essentially only sets the `Range` header. So to replicate you would do the same:

```
url = URI.parse(...)

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.request_uri)
req['Range'] = 'bytes=0-0'

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")

response = http.request(req)
```

Comment: Could this be made shorter, I wonder? In the bash example, doing this is just an extra flag. But in Ruby that’s four extra lines, including creating two extra variables. What’s the shortest this could be, while still correct?

Comment: With Net::HTTP there is no shorter way. I looked at the documentation and this is the most compact form I could find. But if you use another gem, then you can likely make it shorter. HTTParty or Faraday are a couple of gems that can probably do this with 1-2 lines.

Comment: But nothing of course prevents you from writing your own method wrapper around this code. Then you can do it in one line.